# Assigning audio file on server to variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, converters, wav, flac

I am trying to convert a .wav file to .flac file using Rillke's flac.js

https://github.com/Rillke/flac.js

The example provided is based around a file being uploaded by a user using `<input type="file" />`

```
$input = $('input')
...
$input.change(function() {
var f = this.files[0]
...
```

How can I set `var f` to an audio file that's already saved on the server? I want to remove the upload process and just run the conversion script for a file stored on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "set var f to an audio file" do you mean just the filename (a string)?

Comment: No. The contents of the file too.
When I alert(this.files[0]), I get: [object File]

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution